# VARIANT to VariantWrapper C#

Tags: c#, visual-c++, com, com-interop, winforms-interop

this is the C++ code

```
bool wait=false;
int temp1=0;
int temp=0;
VARIANT    temper= { 0 };
temper.boolVal    =    wait? VARIANT_TRUE : VARIANT_FALSE;
server.ExecuteCommand(temp1, temp, nullptr, &temper);
```

How to do the same thing with VariantWrapper in C#

```
bool wait=false;
int temp1=0;
int temp=0;
object varWrapper = new VariantWrapper(??????);
var result = server.ExecuteCommand(temp1, temp, null, ref 
varWrapper);
```

Comment: That C++ code is quite borken, it actually creates a variant of type VT_EMPTY.  So must not assign the boolVal field.  Using `object varWrapper = null;` is your best bet, but if that boolVal actually matters then you're stuck.

Comment: VariantWrapper is rarely needed. Show us how ExecuteCommand is declared and used in C# and in C++